# Lambda anonymous method in messagebox.show

Tags: c#, winforms, lambda

I'm just playing with anonymous methods, and I was wondering why this code will not compile. Messagebox show takes a string, I'm trying to return it a string.

```
            MessageBox.Show(() => 
            {
                if (button1.Text == "button1")
                {
                   return "ok";
                }
                else
                {
                   return "not button1 text";
                }
            });
```

Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type.

Can someone explain why? Am I missing a cast?

Comment: You should not use asp.net tag as this post has nothing to do with ASP .NET, the MessageBox.Show is a Winforms method. A lambda expression tag would be good to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What your piece of code is doing is defining a `Func` that returns a string (`Func<string>`). And then you try to pass that `Func<string>` into `MessageBox.Show` as an argument. Please note that `MessageBox.Show` does not accept `Func<string>` type, it accepts `string` so you cannot pass lamda expression to it this way). But you could do like that:

```
Func<string> yourFunc = () => 
            {
                if (button1.Text == "button1")
                {
                   return "ok";
                }
                else
                {
                   return "not button1 text";
                }
            };

MessageBox.Show(yourFunc());
```